# Would this kind of array be a "Bidirectional Array?"

Tags: arrays, indexing, data-structures, categories, terminology

What are common terms for an array which is addressed from a pivot element (not necessarily the middle), where the first few members belong to one logical category and the rest of the members belong to another logical category?

- "bidirectional array?"
- "array-struct?"
- "ragged array" (special case)?

One simple usage is to store the array *size* (one logical category) in the first element of the array and the array *members* (another logical category) in the remainder of the array.

One implementation might include:

```
// C-like pseudocode
int extract(int * array, int index) { return array [ * array + index ] ; }
```

where the first element of the array stores the offset of the pivot. (Bounds checking code, etc. is left out for the sake of brevity.)

### Background

In his book, [*Capability-Based Computer Systems*](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Elevy/capabook/), Henry M. Levy describes the stack of the [B5000](https://www.smecc.org/The%20Architecture%20%20of%20the%20Burroughs%20B-5000.htm) as it relates to the operation of subroutines (ch 2, sec 2; emphasis added):

> When a subroutine is called, input parameters... are saved on the stack... One of the subroutine mode syllables allows stack addressing relative to the [next available stack location] in the *positive direction* (to access [local variables]) or the *negative direction* (to access [subroutine arguments]).

More recently, in his [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHCupaXkTEY) with the [Silicon Valley Forth Interest Group](http://forth.org/svfig/), Bill Ragsdale discusses using arrays in a similar manner, where, in one direction, array attributes (e.g., array size and dimensions) are stored, and, in the other direction, the array members are stored.

I have also heard and seen that some compilers (e.g., with strings in C++) and/or languages (Forth, Pascal) use the first element of a character array to store its length, and the remaining characters to store the characters themselves.

Fortran (77? and up) allows the programmer to specify array indexing starting at an arbitrary integral value on a per-array basis via `DIMENSION`. One may apply this feature to the storage of attributes at negative indices and members at non-negative indices.